# JavaScript Store Value from remote source

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, server

I have a local web server which will just return a value on a web page made from PHP. (When I run the script it returns a value from 0 to 100)

For example.
[image: php script]

On my local client side I want to store this value but I'm not sure how.

I know the solution has to be simple, however my research has not found it.

Comment: You can use `localStorage` for requirement if Javascript global variable thing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use **localStorage** or **sessionStorage** (In case of short span of time i.e. until browser is closed)

Answer (score 0):

If you need store data with no expiration date. you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

In localStorage, The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year. You can set your value from remote server by calling by localStorage.setItem("key", value) or localStorage.key=value;

you can get idea from bellow code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
<p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will continue to count (is not reset).</p>
</body>
</html>
```